# The sum of independent weak convergence r.v.s

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence, characteristic-functions

Show that if $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent random variables for $1 \le n \le \infty$, $X_n \Rightarrow X_{\infty}$, and $Y_n \Rightarrow Y_{\infty}$, then $X_n + Y_n \Rightarrow X_{\infty} + Y_{\infty}$. Where $\Rightarrow$ means converge weakly or converge in distribution.

---

The solution as following

Since $X_n \Rightarrow X_{\infty}$ and $Y_n \Rightarrow Y_{\infty}$, we have $\varphi_{X_n}(t) \to \varphi_{X_\infty}(t)$ for all t, and $\varphi_{Y_n}(t) \to \varphi_{Y_\infty}(t)$ for all $t$ by the continuity theorem. And thus $$ \varphi_{X_n + Y_n} (t) = \varphi_{X_n} (t) \varphi_{Y_n}(t) \to \varphi_{X_\infty}(t)\varphi_{Y_\infty}(t){\color{Red} =}  \varphi_{X_\infty + Y_\infty}(t)$$ for all $t$. Since both $\varphi_{X_\infty} (t)$ and $\varphi_{Y_\infty}(t)$ are continuous at $0$, $\varphi_{X_\infty + Y_\infty} (t)$ is continuous at $0$. Therefore by continuity theorem we have $X_n + Y_n \Rightarrow X_\infty + Y_\infty$.

---

I don't understand why $\varphi_{X_\infty}(t)\varphi_{Y_\infty}(t){\color{Red} =}  \varphi_{X_\infty  + Y_\infty}(t)$ for all $t$.If we can illustrate $X_\infty$ and $Y_\infty$ are independent,then the equality holds clearly.But how to prove it from $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent.

Answer (score 3):

The claim is false. Let $X_n\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1),Y_n\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, independent $\forall n$ and $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1),Y=-X$. Then $X_n \stackrel{\textrm{w}}\to X$, $Y_n \stackrel{\textrm{w}}\to Y$ but $X_n+Y_n\stackrel{\textrm{w}}{\to}Z$ where $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$ and $X+Y=0$

Comment: Wow! But in Sidney's *A probability Path*, the author gave an exercise:
Suppose $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent for each $n$ and $$X_n \Rightarrow X_{0},Y_n \Rightarrow Y_{0}.$$ Prove using characteristic functions that $$X_n + Y_n \Rightarrow X_{0} + Y_{0}.$$ 
This excerise is wrong?

Comment: The exercise is not wrong. $X_0,Y_0$ are assumed to be independent, because the author uses the index $n \geq 0$, and he says 'independent for each $n$'.

Comment: I don't know why $X_{0}$ and $Y_{0}$ are independent from $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent for each $n$.Let $n=0$?

Comment: It is indeed ambiguous, but from Exercise 2 we have a context

Comment: Oh ,Thanks for your mention. Yes, in  $9.9$ Excercise $2$,the author said that "Let $\left\{X_n,n\geq 0 \right\}$ be a sequence of random variables." I missed it,since I dealed with my posted problem (Exercise 5 ) directly.